# Send JSON in request without backslashes

Tags: json, spring-boot

```
{
  "creditRiskData": "{\"externalQueryDate\":\"4018-11-23T19:13:19.392+03:00\"}",
  "identityTypeCode": "TTN",
  "identityValue": "9999999998"
}
```

this is my request which i can send in `swagger` but without backslashes, it gives error.

I am using `objectmapper` to parse the JSON after i get from request:

```
 private LocalDate getExternalQueryDate(String creditRiskData) throws IOException {

        return objectMapper.readValue(creditRiskData, CreditRiskDataDTO.class).getExternalQueryDate();

    }
```

this is class to parse to be able to get the JSON into a variable:

```
public class CreditRiskDataDTO {

    private LocalDate externalQueryDate;

    public LocalDate getExternalQueryDate() {
        return externalQueryDate;
    }

    public void setExternalQueryDate(LocalDate externalQueryDate) {
        this.externalQueryDate = externalQueryDate;
    }
}
```

From frontend, javascript sends without backslashes. Like this:

```
{
  "creditRiskData": "{"externalQueryDate":"4018-11-23T19:13:19.392+03:00"}",
  "identityTypeCode": "TTN",
  "identityValue": "9999999998"
}
```

but swagger gives this error:

```
"fault": {
    "objectErrors": [
      {
        "objectName": "",
        "message": "JSON parse error: Unexpected character ('e' (code 101)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('e' (code 101)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 2, column: 25]"
      }
```

Is there any way to solve this? Sending without backslashes?

For example, when i get the data from `get method`, it gives like this:

```
"{\"externalQueryDate\":\"5018-11-23\",
```

with backslashes. But in `Mysql` database, it is without backslashes. But swagger shows with backslashes.

This is get:

```
 CreditRisk creditRisk = creditRiskDataRepository.findByOrganisationId(organisation.getId());


            return creditRisk != null ? creditRisk.getCreditRiskDataCodeBased() : null;
```

When i send this:

```
   {
  "creditRiskData": {"externalQueryDate":"4018-11-23T19:13:19.392+03:00"},
  "identityTypeCode": "TTN",
  "identityValue": "9999999997"
}
```

it gives that error

```
 "fieldErrors": [
      {
        "filterName": "creditRiskInformationCodeTermBasedRequest.identityTypeCode",
        "errorCode": "NotEmpty",
        "objectName": "creditRiskInformationCodeTermBasedRequest",
        "message": "must not be empty",
        "variables": [],
        "fieldName": "identityTypeCode"
      },
      {
        "filterName": "creditRiskInformationCodeTermBasedRequest.identityValue",
        "errorCode": "NotEmpty",
        "objectName": "creditRiskInformationCodeTermBasedRequest",
        "message": "must not be empty",
        "variables": [],
        "fieldName": "identityValue"
      }
    ]
```

Comment: In your sample you have 2 opening `{` but only one closing `}`. This is not valid json.

Comment: @Benoit i fixed. Wrong copy paste

Comment: What is your problem in escaping the quotes using a backslash?

Comment: @escapeVelocity do i have to use backslashes? Are not there any way? In front end, front end developers should put backslashes.

Comment: Also you should not have double-quote around `{"externalQueryDate":"4018-11-23T19:13:19.392+03:00"}`

Comment: @Benoit i tried with it but it gives error. I added to bottom of question.